# Pronoun use in sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Her dances are mathematical explorations of geometric shapes, and her dancers are expressionless, genderless instruments ***who*** etch intricate  patterns on the floor in precisely timed repetitive sequences of relatively simple steps.

1. Why is it written *who*? Why no other pronoun like *which* or *that*?
2. Which is the main part of the sentence, which is the secondary part of the sentence?

Comment: As a learner: I think "who" is a subject there and its reference is "dancers", so you cannot remove it or replace it by "that". Also, for refering to the human beings, we should use "who" as the relative pronoun. It's a restrictive relative clause in other words. Regarding the distance between the pronoun and the referent, I have no idea if that's a good thing to do. Maybe it's not the case here, and in a literay style, the author treated instruments as humans and the referent is "instruments".

Comment: thank you for editing, Jan Doggen

Comment: @Cardinal you can use *that* to refer to people, as in *that's the man that shouts at squirrels* Also, this sentence would make sense if the pronoun referred to *expressionless, genderless instruments*. There would be a change of meaning, but it would still be grammatical.

Comment: @Minty I said that because I was taught not to change the relative pronoun when it's the subject and it makes a restrictive clause. Maybe that was the case for formal contexts, I honestly don't know!

Answer (score 1):

Her dances are mathematical explorations of geometric shapes, and her dancers are expressionless, genderless instruments who etch intricate patterns on the floor in precisely timed repetitive sequences of relatively simple steps.

As written, who refers to the dancers.

better written as: her expressionless, genderless dancers are instruments that etch intricate patterns...

OR

her dancers are expressionless, genderless instruments,  who etch intricate patterns on the floor

Answer (score 0):

> Her dances are mathematical explorations of geometric shapes, and her dancers are expressionless, genderless instruments **who** etch intricate patterns on the floor in precisely timed repetitive sequences of relatively simple steps.

This sentence depends upon metaphor for its effect.

Metaphor is when you make a comparison between two things by saying that they are literally the same thing - even though they are **not** literally the same thing, and you expect your audience to understand that. For instance, if you say "last night's blind date was a trainwreck," you expect your audience will understand two things:

1. The date did **not** involve any actual, literal trains being wrecked;
2. The date was a horrifying disaster, like a trainwreck is a horrifying disaster.

To communicate successfully with a metaphor, you need to communicate on two levels - the literal truth, and the impression as well.

The pronouns "that" and "which" can be used for people, or for objects. The pronoun "who," though, is only for people. So in the context of this sentence, the use of the pronoun "who" communicates that the dancers really are literally people - even though the point of the sentence is that they are presented as if they were just objects.